# What's the simplest way to write portable dynamically loadable libraries in C++?

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries, portability, dynamic-loading

I'm working on a project which has multiple similar code paths which I'd like to separate from the main project into plugins. The project must remain cross-platform compatible, and all of the dynamic library loading APIs I've looked into are platform specific.

What's the simplest way to create a dynamic library loading system which can be compiled and run on multiple operating systems without extra modification of the code? Ideally, I'd like to write one plugin, and have it work on all the operating systems the project supports.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will have to use platform dependent code for the **loading system**. It's different loading a DLL on Windows than loading a *shared object* in Unix. But, with a couple of `#ifdef` you will be able to have mostly the same code base in the loader.

Having said that, I think you can make your plugins platform independent. Of course, you will have to compile it for every platform, but the code will be 99% the same.

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic library loading an Windows and Unix/Linux works with 3 functions. A pair of functions to load/unload the libraries, and another function to get the address of a function in the library. You can easily write a wrapper around these three functions to provide cross operating systems suppport.

Answer (score 4):

> Ideally, I'd like to write one plugin, and have it work on all the operating systems the project supports.

Few things from top of my head:

- Avoid static objects in the dynamic libraries. Provision proper initialization methods/functions to allocate the objects. The issues which occur during library being loaded by the OS (this is when the c'tors for static objects are called) are very hard to debug - next only to the multi-threading issues.
- Interface headers may not contain code. No inline methods, no preprocessor defines. That is to avoid tainting application with the code from particular version of library, making it impossible to replace the library at later time.
- Interface headers may not contain implementation classes themselves - only abstract classes and [factory functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Similar to the previous point - to avoid application depend on the particular version of the classes. Factories are needed as a way for user application to instantiate the concrete implementation classes.
- When introducing new version of an interface, to keep things somehow backward compatible, do not modify existing abstract class - create new abstract class inherited from it and add new methods there. Change factory to return the new version. (Recall MS' IInterface, IInterface2, IInterface3 and so on.) In the implementation, use newer version of the abstract class. That by polymorphism would make the implementation backward compatible with the older interface versions. (That obviously calls for periodic interface maintenance and clean-ups - to remove the old cruft.)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the boost.extension library, it is not really part of boost, but you can find it in the sandbox. It is kind of frozen also, but overall the library is stable and easy to use.